# python matrix sum 'numpy.int32' object is not iterable

Tags: python

```
for i in range(0,300):

  for j in range(0,300):

    h = sum(w[i,j]-i)
```

w is a 300*300 marix,
when I run the module,  'numpy.int32' object is not iterable. How can I solve this problem? Thank you!!!

Comment: ... what is this code suppose to do? What is `sum(w[i,j]-i)` suppose to do?

Comment: I want to sum up every element minus its axis number in the matrix.

Comment: What does that mean? Can you give an example?'

Comment: Do you mean something like `(arr - np.arange(arr.shape[0])[:,None]).sum()`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean, sorry for my poor description, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`w[i,j]` is a scalar (one integer number). `w[i,j]-i` is a scalar, too. You cannot pass a scalar to `sum()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
h = 0
for i in range(0,300):
    for j in range(0,300):
        h = h + w[i,j] - i
print ("sum of matrix minux axis is", h)
```